# ypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined at new AnimationTrigger (browser.es5.js:2421)

Tags: angular

I am getting following error while running simple angular animation demo

AppComponent_Host.html:1 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at new AnimationTrigger (browser.es5.js:2421)
    at buildTrigger (browser.es5.js:2405)
    at InjectableAnimationEngine.webpackJsonp.../../../animations/@angular/animations/browser.es5.js.AnimationEngine.registerTrigger (browser.es5.js:4446)
    at animations.es5.js:248
    at Array.forEach ()
    at AnimationRendererFactory.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser/animations.es5.js.AnimationRendererFactory.createRenderer (animations.es5.js:248)
    at DebugRendererFactory2.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.DebugRendererFactory2.createRenderer (core.es5.js:13499)
    at createComponentView (core.es5.js:12099)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13467)
    at Object.debugCreateComponentView [as createComponentView] (core.es5.js:12811)